# Javascript contacts not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am trying to develop a simple application access all the contacts using phonegap. But every time i try to run the code , onError() function is getting called instead of onSuccess().

Here is the code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


function onDeviceReady()
{
     var options = new ContactFindOptions();
     options.filter = "";
     options.multiple=true;
     var fields = ["displayName"];
     navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);

}

var names=[];

function onSuccess(contacts)
{
      for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) 
      {
      names.push("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
      }
      alert(names);
}

function onError(contactError)
{
      alert('error !!');
}




</script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Welcome To My Homepage</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <p>
    Hello Phonegap!!
    </p>
  </div>

  <div data-role="footer">
    <h1>Footer Text</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you add what is in [contactError](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_contacts_contacts.md.html#contactError)

Comment: Try removing options.filter = "";

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">       

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        var options = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter="";
        options.filter="";
        options.multiple=true;
        var fields = ["*"];  //"*" will return all contact fields
        navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);

    }       

    // display the address information for all contacts
    function onSuccess(contacts) {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(contacts))
         var li = '<ol data-inset="true" data-role="listview">';
         $.each(contacts, function(key, value) {
                if(value.name){
                    $.each(value.name, function(key, value) {
                       if(key == 'formatted'){
                           name = value;
                       }

                    });
                }
                if(value.phoneNumbers){
                    $.each(value.phoneNumbers, function(key, value) {
                        phone = value.value;
                    });
                }                    
                li += '<li style="text-decoration:none;">'+name+' '+phone+'</li>';
         });

        li += '</ol>';            
        $("#contact").html(li).trigger('create');
        $("#contact").listview("refresh");

    };

    function onError(contactError) {
        alert('onError!');
    };
</script>
```